# Getting error message "Class 'Foo' not found" when implement Class from adding package(TAD-PHP), downloaded via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, service-provider, packagist

I downloaded the package named "**TAD-PHP**" from **Packagist** via **composer** to use in my project at Laravel, but **the package has no default service provider**.

So, I cant to register that package and cant make the alias.

**In local**, everything is **fine**. I can use that package in every my own class.

But, when I uploaded **in hosting**, I've get an **error** massage: `Class 'TADPHP\TADfactory' not found`.

I really dont understand how it can. My opinion say: maybe because there is haven't default service provider from the package. Is that matter? if my opinion is right, how can I do to **make** the ***service provider*** for TAD PHP as *manually*?

---

I use this command to download this: `composer require ahmedali5530/tad-php`, and this is the site where I download the package: *https://packagist.org/packages/ahmedali5530/tad-php*

Comment: The package you're trying to use is 5 years old and probably abandoned, see here: https://github.com/ahmedali5530/tad-php

Comment: but, the fact I still can use that package. so, what should I do? :(

Comment: Did your run composer dump-autoload on your server after uploading?

Comment: of course, but still nothing happen :( help me out please :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know with this error.

The only probability this error is about sensitive case. When I was developed that program, my OS is Windows, which is they are not need sesitive case anymore. But, when i was uploaded into hosting with Linux that spec, Linux needs sensitive case!.

Which is TADfactory in linux is unknown library. Because, Linux just know TADFactory library.

So, from this case, we all know that we must to be wise coder when develop a program. :)